# How to print an arrayList object's values instead of its location

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have been having issues with a class named arrayList that represents a list of objects and supports random access to its objects via a numeric position index.

The toString method should build and return a string containing the string representations of the objects currently accessible in the array, and when the logical size is 0; the string is empty.

I use a tester class to call the arrayList class.

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        arrayList a1, a2;
        a1 = new arrayList();
        a2 = new arrayList(5);
        a2.size();
        System.out.println(a1.toString());
        //System.out.println(a2.toString());
    }
}

public class arrayList {
    private int logicalSize;
    private static Object[] array = new Object[0];
    private Object[] original;
    private Object removedElement;

    public arrayList() {
        Object[] array = new Object[]{null,null,null,null,null}; 
    }

    public arrayList(int i) {
        logicalSize = i;
        Object[] array = new Object[logicalSize - 1];
    }

    public arrayList(Object[] array) {
        logicalSize = array.length;
        Object[] copyArray = array;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(Object[] array) {
        String str = " ";

        for(int a = 0; a < logicalSize; a++) {
            str = str + array[a];
        }

        str = str + "\nSize: " + size();
        return str;
    }  

    public int size() {
        int length = array.length;
        return length;
    }
}
```

When the above code is run, I get "arrayList@(memmorylocation)".

I am only using a single dimensional array (the others are for a later part) and have tried various methods to get it to print anything but the location, including removing the loop that should print out values from the toString, and just doing:

```
System.out.println(a1);
```

instead of:

```
System.out.println(a1.toString());
```

but no matter what I change I still print out its location, and not its value.

How do I print the value instead of the location? I am using the BlueJ IDE.

Comment: Have you overridden the toString() method from java.lang.Object?

Comment: as @JBNizet said, if you are wanting to use the call you are already using "System.out.println(a1);", you have to override the default toString() method.   If you are trying to implement your own toString() method, follow the instruction in Jean_Franscois's answer below.

Comment: I don't want to discourage you; but there are many (more or less) subtle problems in your code. It starts with violation of naming conventions; and then there are many statements that dont have effects; like `Object[] array = new Object[]{null,null,null,null,null}; ` in your constructor. You are not initializing your member array; you are init'ing a locale variable ... that fades away, as soon as the constructor is left. Meaning: many bugs in there ...

Comment: @EddyG yeah I knew I had more problems, but if I prefer beeing able to see before pulling errors. The error you mentioned came up in my next segment; `public Object get(int a)
    {
        if (a < 0 || a >= logicalSize)
        {
             throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Positions must be from position 0 to position "+(logicalSize - 1));
        }
        else
        {
            return array[a];
        }
    }`
But shouldnt my declaration of `private static Object[] array = new Object[0];`
solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you call the default method `toString` instead of the one you defined.

```
System.out.println(a1.toString());
```

Your method is supposed to receive an array as argument :

```
public String toString(Object[] array)
```

so pass in an array, or correctly override the `toString()` method. Note that using the `@Override` annotation would have told you that you did not override the method, which would probably made you avoid this mis-understanding.

By the way, by convention java class should start with an uppercase. So by convention, you should name your class `ArrayList` which already exists in `java.util` (as you probably know). You should change the name of your class for something more appropriate.

This syntax is repugnant :

```
Object[] array = new Object[]{null,null,null,null,null};
```

You want to do instead :

```
Object[] array = new Object[5];
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I totally missed I was trying to pass it an array. I expanded to

Object[] array = new Object[]{null,null,null,null,null};

to try to get anything working

Comment: @Packerfan504 if you want to print the array of the class, simply change the signature to `toString()`, there is no need to re-pass the class object in argument.